# Computer Specs High Terrible Performance

Tags: windows-10, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-core-i7, fps

I wasn’t sure if this was the right place to ask but I’m just going to throw it out there. I’ve got a laptop I bought a while ago which has supposedly wild specifications for a laptop. It’s an ASUS Q552u Notebook PC. I wouldn’t take the time to look it up it is virtually nonexistent in the Internet. The specs are:

- Intel Core i7 6th Gen
- NVidia GeForce 940 M
- 12 GB RAM
- 4K Screen
- 1 TB Hard Drive

The problem is (to give you an idea) it can barely run a game like fortnite over 15 fps on the lowest graphics settings! I don’t know what the problem is. It gives about 2 threads from the graphics card. How can it be so slow? Is it the graphics card? I can’t find any documentation about the ghost of a computer anywhere.

Comment: Were you running the game in 4k resolution? The graphics card isn't really "high" specs.

Comment: Your laptop has hybrid graphics. Make sure you're using Nvidia for games and not the CPU integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: No I’m running at 480p and where can I configure it to use the GPU? I changed the settings in some softwares but is there a way to make it default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty information about [this laptop online](https://laptoping.com/specs/product/asus-q552ub-bhi7t12-2-in-1-15-6-touch-laptop-intel-core-i7-12gb-ram-1tb-hdd-aluminum-black/).

It's difficult to say for sure what is causing the issue.  If [this link](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/fortnite/15349) is anything to go by the system exceeds the minimum specs but does not meet the recommended speed with respect of GPU.  If you are running this game at 4k, then your system is most likely not fast enough - 4k requires at least 4 times the GPU power of 1080p.

I do note that it has a spinning disk - you should check to make sure there is not a lot of disk reads/writes going on - if so, this could explain the slowness of the system.  Also, run some stress testing on the system and make sure that it is adequately cooling - if not, the CPU (and maybe the GPU?) may be throttling down to prevent overheating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’m running at 480p. How can I check how much is written onto the disk and do a stress test? Sorry but I don’t know much about computers :). Although my computer gets pretty hot sometimes I just thought it was normal. How could I improve the cooling?

Comment: Many systems have a hard disk light which flashed watch time there is activity. If that flicking or solid on when playing the game it's a good indication of disk io. Lots of ways to do a stress test - one is to run prime95 and monitor the temperature reported by CPU. Improved cooling depends on the system, but usually a fan blowing air over the laptop, and using it on a hard surface,  or raised so air can run across the bottom as well)

Comment: Oh alright. I’ll check. Thnx. Also, do you think it’s worth switching from HDD to SSD?

Comment: Save for where large RAID/NAS installs are required, I would always choose SSD -it  is way, way faster on the part of a system that's typically a bottleneck, and at least 10 times more reliable on the most unreliable component in a PC (Just be aware the risk of *sudden, catastrophic* failure on SSD is much higher then HDD and make sure you have robust backups)

Comment: K. Do you think the Samsung 840 Evo would fit in my laptop in replacement of the HDD? Is there a SSD that you would recommend?

Comment: I'm not near a PC, so can't easily check, but a Samsung EV840 should be fine. I typically purchase newer Samsung EVO850 drives, but nothing wrong with the evo840.

Comment: I cleared off a lot of disc space, increased cooling, and it runs everything perfect! I never knew my pc was close to this powerful. Thanks so much!